# Unresolved dependencies for np 0.2.0 with SBT 0.13?

Tags: scala, sbt

Scala **2.10.2** and SBT **0.13**

I'm trying to use the **np** plugin and added the following lines to `../0.13/np.sbt`:

```
seq(npSettings:_*)

(NpKeys.defaults in (Compile, NpKeys.np)) ~= {
  _.copy(org="me.lessis", version="0.1.0-SNAPSHOT")
}
```

and this to `<home-directory>/.sbt/plugins.sbt`

```
addSbtPlugin("me.lessis" % "np" % "0.2.0")

resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-releases",url("http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

When I execute `sbt run` I am getting :

```
[info] Updating {file:/home/Projects/helloSbt/}default-310e5b...
[info] Resolving me.lessis#np;0.2.0 ...
[warn]  module not found: me.lessis#np;0.2.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn] /home/.ivy2/local/me.lessis/np/scala_2.10/sbt_0.12/0.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/me.lessis/np/scala_2.10/sbt_0.12/0.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/me/lessis/np_2.10_0.12/0.2.0/np-0.2.0.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: me.lessis#np;0.2.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      me.lessis:np:0.2.0 (sbtVersion=0.12, scalaVersion=2.10)
[warn] 
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: me.lessis#np;0.2.0: not found
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Feb 6, 2014 9:23:17 AM
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @ajozwik done that, I wrote in my question post "and this to /.sbt/plugins.sbt addSbtPlugin("me.lessis" % "np" % "0.2.0")"

Answer (score 2):

For scala 2.10 you have to use sbt 0.13. I tried with sbt 0.13

Open in browser link:
http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/me.lessis/np/scala_2.10/

There is only:

`sbt_0.13/`

For scala 2.9.2 you need to use sbt 0.12

==========================

**Update:**

- Remove global configuration from $HOME/.sbt (plugins.sbt). or make or action from fresh user account (new user never used sbt)
- Create empty directory **test**
- Go to **test**
- Create directory **project**
- Go to **project**
- Create plugins.sbt with content as above in question
- Go to **test** directory
- run `sbt test` or other command
- see output - me.lessis#np;0.2.0 should be downloaded

Comment: Thanks but I am using 2.10.2

Comment: Thanks , but I am using sbt 0.13

Comment: In your log is `sbtVersion=0.12`. Check if you override sbt version in your build (build.sbt in your project or other places)

Comment: did that(add the key to build.sbt and at the plugin sbt file), when I am running sbt-version I am getting 0.13. but when running I am getting same result as above

Comment: I just create empty project with project/plugins.sbt and sbt downloaded file for me without errors.

Comment: any chance that you can put it somewhere for me to download , so I can see what went wrong on my side ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt` (note the **0.13/plugins** in the path) or even better for quick scan of the plugins installed, use `.sbt/0.13/plugins/np.sbt` so it's clear from the file name(s) about the plugins.

Please also note that from the question it appears that you're using SBT **0.12**:

> me.lessis:np:0.2.0 (sbtVersion=0.12, scalaVersion=2.10)

Add `project/build.properties` under `helloSbt` with the following line to have **0.13** be in use:

```
sbt.version=0.13.1
```